# Profiler Windows x32 problem

Tags: c++, .net, profiler

I run Windows XP SP3 on my virtual machine.

There I use Visual C++ Express a CLR profiler for .net 2.0
I run x86 profiler(choosing between x86 and x64), choose simple Visual C++ application which outputs 1000 times "Hello world" string.

What the profiler does is shows the message "Waiting for application to start command language runtime"
and nothing more.

So, what's the problem?

Comment: The free CLR Profiler is worth what you paid for it.  Not sure if it supports C++/CLI programs, I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't.  Do make sure you actually created a managed program, it certainly won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CLR profiler cannot profile native C++ code, only CLR (Common Language Runtime) the virtual box that runs .Net code.

Try downloading the free edition of AQTime at http://smartbear.com/products/free-tools/aqtime-standard/

That one should be able to profile your C++ code (if you follow some rules, you might need to have it in debug mode and generate a map file, it's been a while since I profiled native code).